# Don't want to change font size on resizing windows form

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, resize, wpf-controls

I have one windows form and one user control. Windows form is having 4 user control form in grid. User control form is having Grid. This grid is having many TextBlock. When I resize windows form , these text block is also resized and fontsize of text inside that is also changed. But I want fix size of font across all grid in windows form (Say 1st grid of user control in all user control hosted by windows form must have same font size.) When windows form size is small at that time text can be trimmed (if text doen't fit in available space) but font size should not be reduce in particular user control form hosted by windows form.

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="text"
               FontSize="16"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

This is sample xaml code for user control file.. List of TextBlock keeps on going. I have problem with first textblock. It will take text from one parameter. If in windows form one usercontrol's first grid is having small text at that time fontsize is high. But if other usercontrol's first grid is having very large text, at that time font size for that is small. So it looks weird that in same windows form differnt fontsize exists.

So can anyone help me with this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is *not* standard for Windows to alter the `FontSize` property of *any* control. Therefore, I suggest to you that YOU are doing it inadvertently in some code that you have not shown here. Also, you can add `TextElement.FontSize="16"` to your declaration of your `Grid` and *all* of the controls inside the `Grid` will inherit this value.

Comment: "try <Grid TextElement.FontSize="10">

Comment: TextElement.FontSize is not coming inside grid. I tried style to fix fontsize but its not working. It still vary across the window withing different user control.

Comment: I have created style inside grid to override inherited properties. But it's still not working. Font size keeps on changing on resizing. I want fix font size. Any suggestion?